Should we combine trig solutions to 2nd order ODEs?
Suppose you solve a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients and get the homogeneous solution $y_h = e^{t} \left(4\cos(5t)+3\sin(5t) \right)$, courtesy of some complex roots to the auxiliary equation. Without much justification, my textbook combines these into $y_h = 5e^{t} \cos(5t - \frac{\pi}{4})$. This is great and all--I can follow how they did it--but I'm curious about the pros/cons of doing this.
For instance, while we now get a single trig function, if I had to later solve for a particular solution and got $y_p = Ce^{t}\sin(5t)$, it may look like this solution is linearly independent from the homogeneous solution because it's not longer clear that $e^{t}\sin(5t)$ was part of the homogeneous solution in the first place.
So I guess my questions are: Is combining the trig parts in the homogeneous solution only really useful for identifying the period, phase shift, and starting amplitude of the solution? and Is it more or less common to leave the homogeneous solution split into its two trig functions to avoid potentially getting incorrect particular solutions later?

You will never get incorrect solutions from it. Does you book show the process? Also your book is wrong....it can't be $\frac{π}{4}$. Try expanding it

I don't understand why your homogeneous solution doesn't have two free parameters. Shouldn't it span a two dimensional space?

It follows a method like this
$$y=a\cos x+b\sin x \\
\implies y=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\bigg(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos x +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin x\bigg)$$
Considering $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ as $\cos \phi$,we get
$$y=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos \phi \cos x+\sin \phi \sin x)\\
\implies y=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x-\phi)$$
If it was a wave equation, then this $\phi$ indicates your phase change, $x$ represents the displacement, period shall be $2π$, amplitude will be $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
For your question,
The value of $\phi=\cos^{-1} \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos^{-1}\frac{4}{5}≈37°=\frac{37π}{180}$
Your book is wrong, the correct conversion is
$$y=5e^t\cos(5x-\frac{37π}{180})$$
This doesn't cause any type of data loss. Instead this helps you picture the equation as a single trigonometric function instead of two. It utilises the fact that $a\cos x+b\sin x$ will always have a period of $2π$ always, just like a normal $\sin$ or $\cos$ function.

While I appreciate your thorough answer, it doesn't really answer my question :(
Perhaps I'll reword it: How would you know (looking at the solution you came up with) that your solution spans a 2D space, and that (e^t)sin(5t) was already a solution (for when considering potential answers for the particular solution, specifically the linearly independent part)?

It seems I'm missing something. It doesn't span a 2d space at all, because there is only one free parameter, i.e. $f(t)$. Shouldn't homogenous solutions be expressible in the form of $f(x,y)$.
